# Motor insurance terms

Tags: car-insurance

Recently I have purchase motor insurance which includes following wording:

> Except for any person named against this Endorsement in the Schedule,
>   we will not pay for any claim which arises while your car is being
>   driven by, or in the charge of any person under 30 years of age.

Does that mean that the person purchasing the policy is allowed to drive if s/he is under 30?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Except for any person named against this Endorsement in the Schedule,
>   we will not pay for any claim which arises while your car is being
>   driven by, or in the charge of any person under 30 years of age.

If the driver is under 30 they will not cover any claim unless you named them in the documentation for the policy.

There should be a part of the policy where you specify who is covered: That would include a spouse, or children, or parents. You will probably have to be specific, because their data (age, gender), and driving history will be used to calculate the price of the policy.

Comment: what if the policy holder is under 30? the policy holder is named as a Driver

Comment: The policy holder is named.

Comment: I take from this that if policy holder is named as a driver and is under 30 he will be covered. Thanks

Comment: Insurance rates for people under 30 are normally higher than those for older people, because teenagers tend to have more accidents. I think the idea here is that if your teenage son or daughter is going to drive the car, you have to have them named in the policy and pay a higher rate. You can't just give the parent's name, pay the lower "grown up" rate, and then let your teenager drive the car.